# Mysql access denied error 1045

Tags: mysql, redhat

I'm trying to connect to mysql on redhat 6.4 (On VM), but I'm getting the below error using this command line :

```
mysql -u root
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Coudl you help with this please ?

Thank's
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would try to include the password

```
   mysql --user=user_name --password db_name
```

Comment: are you  100% sure the password you are using belongs to that database?,

Comment: Yes sure, I changed the pwd and it works fine now, thank you